# How to move data points into individual rows?

Tags: r

```
Data currently looks like this:

Distance
0[]
1[.8]
2[.7 .5]
3[.8 .5 .2]
4[.4 .8 .8 .7]
```

I want the following:

```
.8
.7
.8
.4
.5
.5
.8
.2
.8
.7
```

Basically, first number in each row, then second, then third

Code

```
data2 <- substring(data$Distance, 2) 
data3 <- data.frame(dist2 = scan(text=gsub("\\d+\\[|[^.0-9]+","\n",data2),quiet = TRUE))
```

This gets me

```
.8
.7
.5
.8
.5
.2
.4
.8
.8
.7
```

This got me each number in one row before going to the next row

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could use `gsub` to delete all non-numeric except `.` and any numeric before `[` then use `read.table`

```
 read.table(text=gsub("\\d+\\[|[^.0-9]+","\n",data$Distance))
    V1
1  0.8
2  0.7
3  0.5
4  0.8
5  0.5
6  0.2
7  0.4
8  0.8
9  0.8
10 0.7
```

Comment: I get this: [1] 0.0000000 1 0.8 2 0.7 0.5 3 0.8 0.5 0.2... There is the 1, 2, 3... still in the data. How do I remove those? Thanks so far!

Comment: @carolin can you paste `dput(head(data))` in your question? It seems your data is different since the regex `\\d+\\[` clearly indicates that all the numbers before `[` must be deleted

Comment: I added the following,       data2 <- substring(data$Distance, 2)      before your code and got it to work.
data3 <- data.frame(dist2 = scan(text=gsub("\\d+\\[|[^.0-9]+","\n",data2),quiet = TRUE))             Now, how do I organize it in a way where it takes the first number in each row, then the second number in each row, then third...